# Email individual row data from mysql to individual users

Tags: php, mysql, email

HI i have 10 rows which contains user information with their id and email. a single user has more than one rows. now i want to send mails to all users which contains their rows data in a single mail

Suppose

```
id  email           item    balance
1   1@example.com   car 200
2   2@example.com   bike    400
3   3@example.com   iron    100
1   1@example.com   cd  500
3   3@example.com   dvd 200
1   1@example.com   books   300
```

Now i am using below script to send multiple email for to all rows to different users.
this is script is sending seperate mail for all rows for a single user.

i want that user1 whose id is 1@example.com will receive only single mail which contains all rows data related to him.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xx","card");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mailtest");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
$to = $row['email'];
$subject = "subject";
$emailBody="";
$emailBody .= "ID: ".$row['id']."; Item: ".$row['item']."; Balance:      ".$row['balance']."; Email: ".$row['email']." \n";

$headers = 'From: Work Pass Notification System <no-reply@someemailaddress>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: someemailaddress' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

      if(mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers)) {
          echo $emailBody;
          echo 'Email sent successfully!';
      } else {
          echo $emailBody;
          die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
      }

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on the rows that you want to merge. This returns a csv for each column you group_concat

```
SELECT id, email, GROUP_CONCAT(item) as item,  GROUP_CONCAT(balance) as balance FROM mailtest GROUP BY id
```

returns

```
id  email           item            balance
1   1@example.com   car,cd,books    200,500,300
2   2@example.com   bike            400
3   3@example.com   iron,dvd        100,200
```

then you can either use `explode()` to get each value in php, or use any other function to work with the returned row data.

you could even mix it with [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to combine the `balance` column

```
SELECT id, email, GROUP_CONCAT(item) as item,  SUM(balance) as balance FROM mailtest GROUP BY id
```

returns

```
id  email           item            balance
1   1@example.com   car,cd,books    1000
2   2@example.com   bike            400
3   3@example.com   iron,dvd        300
```

**edit**
here is one way to do it.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xx","card");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, email, GROUP_CONCAT(item) as item,  GROUP_CONCAT(balance) as balance FROM mailtest GROUP BY id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
$to = $row['email'];
$subject = "subject";
$emailBody="";
// explode the items/balances on the comma's
$items = explode(',',$row['item']);
$balance = explode(',',$row['balance']);
// Create a line for each item/balance
foreach($items as $key => $item){
    $emailBody .= "ID: ".$row['id']."; Item: ".$items[$key]."; Balance:      ".$balance[$key]."; Email: ".$row['email']." \n";}
// add a Total Balance line
$emailBody .= "Total Balance: ".array_sum($balance)."\n";
$headers = 'From: Work Pass Notification System <no-reply@someemailaddress>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: someemailaddress' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

      if(mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers)) {
          echo $emailBody;
          echo 'Email sent successfully!';
      } else {
          echo $emailBody;
          die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
      }

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Pls apply this code in my code and tell me how it will look like, i am unable to understand how to use this

Comment: Thanks its working now please tell me instead of sending values in comma can we send then by rows......

Comment: id email item cost
1 1@example.com car 200
1 1@example.com cd 500
1 1@example.com books 300

Comment: I have updated my answer with how to explode the items/balances, and do a line for each item/balance, and a final line with the total balance. I included line comments where I added/changes your code (except for the mysql query, which is self-explanatory)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put all of the user's information into an Array then loop through?

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xx","card");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mailtest");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){

    $send_details[$row['email']] .= "ID: ".$row['Stu_id']."; Pin No: ".$row['Pin_number']."; name:      ".$row['name']."; Email: ".$row['email']." \n";

}

foreach($send_details as $email => $body){
   // Send the mail
}
```

Comment: I think this code in complete and has some errors kindly correct it and send it to me so that i can check this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do two nested queries (pseudo code)

```
"SELECT DISTINCT email FROM items;"
foreach $email do:
    "SELECT item FROM items WHERE email = $email;"
    clear($all_items)
    foreach $item do:
        $all_items[] = $item
    mail(... $all_items ...)
```

As an alternative use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get all items in a single field:

```
SELECT email, GROUP_CONCAT(item) all_items FROM items GROUP BY email
```

Then put the `all_items` field in your email.